# How do I show a passcode view in an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on an iOS project and would like to secure the app. I have been able to create and passcode view controller and it works fine but I want to present the passcode view whenever the app is about to enter the background or before it enters foreground. I know Appdelegate provides useful methods but how do I implement it to show the passcode view controller. I tried implementing the rootviewcontroller to present the passcode viewcontroller in the Appdelegate but it doesn't work and gives debugger message "attempt to present a viewcontroller that's not in the hierachy".

Answer (score 0):

add this line to viewDidLoad() func:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "showPasscodeView:", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
```

Then present passcode view in showPasscodeView() func.